# How do I convert this to work with the code that I've got in place?

Tags: reactjs

I have successfully converted most of my code to React Hooks with Node for the server that works to write/read to/from the mysql db.  However, I need to be able to use this code somehow for authentication of the username & password:

```
    if (this.state.username === "Tim" && this.state.password === "1234") {
      AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(
       this.state.username,
       this.state.password
      );
       this.props.history.push(`/welcome/${this.state.username}`);

} else {
  this.setState({ showSuccessMessage: false });
  this.setState({ hasLoginFailed: true });
}
```

}

Here is the code where I need to make it work with:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");      

const login = () => {
     Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
     username: username,
     password: password,
      }).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.message) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
       } else {
          setLoginStatus(response.data[0].username)
      }
    });
  };
```

this is what i've tried, but isn't working:

```
   useEffect(() => {
       const navigate = async () => {
       const authorized = await 
       AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin;
       if (username === "Tim" && password === "1234" && authorized) {
       history.push(`/welcome/${username}`);
       } else if (!authorized) {
       history.push("/login");
      }
    };
    navigate();
    },[username,password,history])
```

Comment: seems like you are fussing in calling `registerSuccessfulLogin` function

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked:

```
 const history = useHistory();


 const login = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    }).then((response) => {
   if (response.data.message) {
     setLoginStatus(response.data.message)
   } else {
    setLoginStatus(response.data[0].username)
    AuthenticationService.registerSuccessfulLogin(
      username,
      password
    );
     history.push(`/welcome/${username}`);
  }
});
```

};